# Write down the set that formally represents the ordered triple (a, b, c)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Write down the set that formally represents the ordered triple $(a, b, c)$

How do I write this set formally?

Definition: an ordered
triple $(a, b, c)$ is a mathematical construction that “bundles” three objects a, b and c

So essentially a Cartesian product $A \times B \times C$

Comment: It is possible the question is asking you to combine $(a, b, c) = ((a, b), c)$ and $(a, b) = \{ \{ a \}, \{ a, b \} \}$ and then expand the definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Set Builder Notation is quite handy $$A\times B\times C = \{(a,b,c)\;|\;a\in A,\;b\in B,\;c\in C\}$$